# Apache OFBiz ERP Integration

Tags: erp, ofbiz

I have been trying to integrate Apache OFBiz ERP into my existing web application which is written using Struts2 , Hibernate and Spring . 
  But OFBiz is written with servlets and jsp . Is this at all possible and if yes how .

Comment: Struts(2) is a servlet framework and integration is possible. But OFBiz (my personal opinion) is big, many years old and fat software (like many old systems accepted on the market). I had big trouble to understand it (I'm not beginning java programmer)

Answer (score 1):

OFBiz stands on its own with Tomcat embedded. It's certainly technically possible to use it with Struts2 and Spring but Hibernate is not needed. OFBiz uses its own Entity Engine, the same thas Atlas Jira is using underneath for more than 10 years. And yes, it's not for the faint or heart.